# Which model of Macintosh has the longest battery life?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I was exclusively a PC man (specifically Dell, Gateway, and HP), but I am now planning to buy a Mac, because my sister has a Mac, with a battery life (much) longer than mine, and I would like to benefit from that. Could anyone suggest the best Mac to buy if I want the longest battery life possible. I mean really the longest, even if it sacrifices other things to achieve it.

Comment: Just curious - what types of activities are you planning on doing?

Comment: really just watching movies on netflix, playing some games, because there are really no CONVENIENT places in my house to plug into WHILE using my laptop, so I want a long battery life.

Answer (score 4):

[According to](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_air/select) [Apple's website](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro?aid=AIC-WWW-NAUS-K2-BUYNOW-MACBOOKPRO-INDEX&cp=BUYNOW-MACBOOKPRO), the 13" MacBook Air and all of the MacBook Pros have 7 hours of battery life. This means that there are seven laptops for you to choose from: Four 13" computers, two 15", and one 17". The possibility of getting more than 7 hours exists, because this number is determined in this manner:

> The wireless web test measures battery life by wirelessly browsing 25 popular websites with display brightness set to 50%.

—[Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro?aid=AIC-WWW-NAUS-K2-BUYNOW-MACBOOKPRO-INDEX&cp=BUYNOW-MACBOOKPRO) (at the very bottom of the page, point number 2).

Comment: +1, agreed. Another Apple page that shows all of the laptops is this one: http://www.apple.com/why-mac/compare/notebooks.html

Comment: I'd stay away from the current 15 inch MBP and 11 inch Air - even though the specs show 7 hours for the MBP, most people end up with less if they don't carefully control CPU usage by quitting programs that run much CPU load.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is the entry level 13" MacBook Air is quite miserly, but no where near the battery runtime of the enormous 17 inch MacBook Pro. Even with a high end GPU and CPU - it has so much power it's the winner for all day performance according to people I know that have them.

The current 15 inch MacBook Pro are a bit more power hungry than the ones of the mid 2009 vintage - so if you can wait, many are speculating whatever [new Ivy Bridge based MacBook Pro eventually gets released](http://www.marco.org/2012/03/28/ivy-bridge-schedule) will likely be [less hot (and get better battery life)](http://www.marco.org/2011/10/26/macbook-pro-heat-fan-update) than the current CPU/GPU lineup. If you can't wait and *need, need, need* all day battery life - I'd pick up a used Mid 2009 or early 2010 model and just watch the CPU to make sure you quit programs that will reduce it from 10 hour life down to 5 to 7 life at a more active CPU load. The nice thing about the older mac is you can pin the GPU to the integrated one and know it will be miserly with the power.

---

Now if I don't take your question literally, but wholistically - you should get a $399 iPad and the $999 MacBook Air. Together, they are a potent combination for Netflix and productivity - I could see you getting 10 hours of netflix and 5 hours of laptop life in "one charge"

Comment: Agreed on the battery life of the 17" MBP, but that's a pretty expensive option for what the OP had in mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "battery life".  Charge capacity will decrease over the usable life of the battery, so if you mean "max charge capacity", @Mahnax gives you this information above.

If you mean longest usable life, this is largely dependent on usage patterns.  Different factors play into usable life, as this article points out:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3008527?start=0&tstart=0

The key point of this article is that you should use (read: disconnect from AC power) your battery a little bit every day to get the most usable life out of it.

Comment: I meant find of like, the largest capacity, but at the same time, good durability, or some combination of the 2. because I've seen laptops that start with 2 hour batteries ending up keeping their charge capacity for longer than a 4 hour battery.